# is there a way to specify the maximum length of a preference?

Tags: android

I would like limit a preference string to 20 characters... is there any way to do this? I mean  limit the user to only being allowed 20 characters input.

Comment: yeah limit the amount of characters in the click handler

Comment: How are you creating/defining the preferences?  PreferenceFragment?  Are the preferences defined in code, or XML?

Answer (score 3):

For an `EditText` you can set the maximum length in the layout file using `android:maxLength="20"`

Answer (score 0):

@MisterSquonk is right about how to handle it in the ui.  You should also store it as a character string when saving your preferences.

Comment: It is just in my setttings page... Android auto-magically displays the preferences and lets the user edit them there

Comment: I don't think you can change it then but you could always get the first 20 letters in your code and resave the preference in your code as only the first 20 letters. This way when the user goes back to the preference they can see only the first 20 letters of the preference saved.

Answer (score 0):

If the preference you are asking is the EditTextPreference, you can set its attributes like this.

```
class MyEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {
    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);

        TextView summary = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);
        if (summary != null) {
            summary.setSingleLine();
            summary.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        }
    }
```

But I guess other Preference provides the same onBindView as well for you to override.